# sqlalchemy to object

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

It must be simple but I can't find a way to get this working.
So supposing I create a table or I generate a table object with *autoload* from an existing database, as seen below:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, String, Table

engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
meta = MetaData(bind=engine)

def create_table(meta):
    tbl = Table('User', meta,
            Column('name', String),
            Column('surname', String),
    )

    meta.create_all()
    return tbl

tbl = create_table(meta)
```

And now suppose I want to use a session and something like

```
 session.add(myobject)
```

how do I actually create an object from that table, since trying to call the table directly doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 17, in <module>
    tbl(name='dfd')
TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable
```

So I suppose I need some sort of mapping, but how?

Comment: You should make sure that you're telling sqlalchemy that objects of your *myobject*'s type are mapped to table *tbl*. Through the 'mapper' function... Take a look to http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/mapper_config.html#classical-mappings I don't see that in the example

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to dig into SA for the first time, I would recommend starting directly with the tutorials and then modifying them towards your own use cases. Using SA can be a big jump from the DBAPI approach (at least it was for me and my team).

Your example code is using the core tutorial, which is *not* the ORM interface. Your question mentions using a `mapper` (as does the question title) so you might be happier following the [ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html). Rather than reproducing that code here, I suggest going to that page and working through the example as published.